# How do you scale and tile a bitmap drawable being used as a background?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following code in a drawable bitmap xml file. And the background of a linearLayout set to it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:src="@drawable/background_screen"
        android:tileMode="repeat"
        android:scaleHeight="10"
        android:scaleWidth="10"
        />
```

The image tiles OK, but it doesn't scale. What do I have to do/fix to get it to scale?

Thanks

Comment: But `scale` and `tile` are different ideas, it doesn't make sense to mix them, you scale or you tile.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I get what you are saying. As mentioned below I got what I needed. Thanks again! :)

Comment: Let's say you have a .png which you are tiling but it's too small, so you want to scale it programmatically. Of course you can just scale the original .png, but then the filesize will also increase.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my experience it is better to create different sized bitmaps for each density you are targeting. That way you don't have to worry about these scale attributes and get crisp results on any device.

These scale attributes are not defined for BitmapDrawables. They exist for ScaleDrawables which are meant to scale another drawable. Have a look at:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Scale