# How do items of a LayerList drawable scale to fit the container View?

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-bitmap

From this [developer guide about Layer-list drawables](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#LayerList),

1. > All drawable items are scaled to fit the size of the containing View,
   >   by default. Thus, placing your images in a layer list at different
   >   positions might increase the size of the View and some images scale as
   >   appropriate.

   In the first sentence, they say that the items are scaled to fit the
   container view (and Not that the view is scaled according to the
   size of the items contained in it). Then they say that the size of
   the container view might increase (which means that the View is
   being scaled, right?). **So doesn't the second sentence contradict
   the first one? Can somebody explain what is meant there?**

   ---
2. > *android:drawable*
   >
   > Drawable resource. **Required**. Reference to a drawable resource.
   >
   > ...
   >
   > To avoid scaling items in the list, use a
   >    element inside the  element to specify the drawable...
   >
   > ...
   >
   > For example, the following  defines an item that scales to
   >   fit its container View:
   >
   > ```
   > <item android:drawable="@drawable/image" />
   > ```
   >
   > To avoid scaling, the following example uses a  element with centered gravity:
   >
   > ```
   > <item>
   >   <bitmap android:src="@drawable/image"
   >           android:gravity="center" />
   > </item>
   > ```

   **Again, they say that `android:drawable` is a *required* attribute, and then they give an example which does not use this attribute. What is correct?**

   ---
3. > To avoid scaling items in the list, use a `<bitmap>` element inside the
   >   `<item>` element to specify the drawable and define the gravity to
   >   something that does not scale, such as "center"

   **How is `gravity` scalable and how is `center` as its value make it unscalable?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. It seems that layer-list items are effectively stretched in both X & Y dimensions to fit the container.
2. You need a drawable for each item.  The bitmap child element effectively becomes the drawable for that item.

   If you have an empty item (with no drawable resource), it will cause an error when you try to load the layer-list.
3. [Gravity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Gravity.html) has several options (like `FILL`, which is probably the item's default gravity, or `FILL_HORIZONTAL` that stretch the item to fill its container).

   Additionally, you can set `android:gravity="center"` on an item tag itself (without a `<bitmap>` child) and it seems to have the same effect (in API 23, at least).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @Cristopher_Boyd said. The screen density is also important, so different bitmaps should be created for different screen densities. If there is a single image inside the `drawable` folder directly, it may not scale properly. Hence, generate different images, or place a single image in `drawables-xxhdpi` folder, for example (but not on `drawables`). See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11196513/5189200).

Hope this helps someone,

Xavi